# Why the differential of a function is a linear transformation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations, differential

I try to find some applications of the differential, that weird thing that is a linear transformation, what is the reason of linearity?
And how this linearity works, I mean, there's something fundamental about that linearity? And where we can see the importance of the differential, like in physics or another field of application.

Comment: At a technical level a differential is linear by definition. At a secondary level because linear maps are simple. For example they scale area by a constant factor, called the Jacobian (even in case of nonequal dimensions). Ultimately this is responsible for change of variables formula, area formula, and coarea formula. Linearity of derivative (of local parameterizations) also gives notion of tangent space to manifolds.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli, what does "even in case of nonequal dimensions" mean in your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979094/why-the-differential-of-a-function-is-a-linear-transformation/3979108#comment8209850_3979094)?  If, for example, we have the addition map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, then both $[0, 1) \times [0, 3)$ and $[0, 2) \times [0, 2)$ are taken onto $[0, 4)$.  In what sense is area scaled by a constant factor?

Comment: @LSpice Ok, I thought I would get away with it! If $L\colon R^n \to R^m$ is an injective linear map and $n\leq m$ then for any measurable set $A \subset R^n$ the image $L(A)$ has $n$-dimensional measure equal to $\sqrt{\det(L^tL)} \mathcal{L^n}(A)$, where the $n$-dimesnional measure can be the Hausdorff measure, or the Lebesgue measure on $L(R^n)$ once we identify it  isometrically with $R^n$

Comment: It is a linear function of the differentials of the independent variables. This follows straight from the definition. That is, if $f(x)$ has a derivative $f'(x),$ then $$\mathrm d f(x)=f'(x)\mathrm dx,$$ and it's quite obvious...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is something absolutely fundamental about linearity.  The whole idea of calculus is to approximate a complicated function by a linear one.  You have probably heard the slogan that the tangent line to a function at a point is the best linear fit at that point; this is exactly the connection between the derivative and linearity.

What may trouble you is that what we usually think of as the derivative in Calculus I is *not* linear.  For example, if $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is given by $f(x) = x^3$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, then $f' : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is given by $f'(x) = 3x^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, which is certainly not linear.

The point of multi-variable calculus is that we shift our view:  instead of thinking about the derivative as a *single* function, we think of it as a *family* of functions, one per point.  We'll often write something like ${\operatorname d}f_x$ to emphasise that we are thinking of the derivative function at $x$.  So, with $f$ as above, we would say that ${\operatorname d}f_7$ is, not the *number* $f'(7) = 147$, but the linear function ${\operatorname d}f_7 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by ${\operatorname d}f_7(\Delta x) = 147\Delta x$ for all $\Delta x \in \mathbb R$.  That is, the derivative in the usual Calculus I sense should really just be thought of as the *slope* of the derivative in the more general sense.

In Calculus III, you learn to speak of the Jacobian matrix of a multi-variable function; for example, for the change-of-coördinate function $g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $g(r, \theta) = (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta))$ for all $(r, \theta) \in \mathbb R^2$, we have the Jacobian matrix $\operatorname{Jac} g(r, \theta) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
-r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$ for all $(r, \theta) \in \mathbb R^2$.  This is just another name for the derivative in the sense above, where we think of specifying a linear transformation by its matrix (with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$).  For example, we would write ${\operatorname d}g_{(2, \pi/6)}$ for the linear transformation with matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt3/2 & 1/2 \\
-1 & \sqrt3
\end{pmatrix}$ (with respect to the standard basis), which is to say the linear transformation given by ${\operatorname d}g_{(2, \pi/6)}(\Delta r, \Delta\theta) = (\sqrt3\Delta r/2 + \Delta\theta/2, -\Delta r + \sqrt 3\Delta\theta)$ for all $(\Delta r, \Delta\theta) \in \mathbb R^2$.

You may notice that I have regarded my derivatives as functions of "the same" variables as the original function, annotated with $\Delta$s—hopefully this reminds you of the idea of the differential approximation, according to which we write $f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x)\Delta x$—but this is really a bit deceptive.  In the utmost generality, we have a function $h : M \to N$ between smooth manifolds, and get, for each $m \in M$, a differential function ${\operatorname d}h_m : \operatorname T_mM \to \operatorname T_{h(m)}N$ that is a linear map of tangent spaces.  It just happens that, when our manifolds are vector spaces $V$, there is a natural identification $V \cong \operatorname T_vV$ at each point.

For a very slightly more complicated example, we have maps $h_1 : \mathbb R \to \operatorname S^1$ and $h_2 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ given by $h_1(t) = e^{i t}$ and $h_2(t) = h_1(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$.  These are the same maps except for the codomain, but their derivatives are quite different.

Namely, for all $t \in \mathbb R$, we have canonical identifications $\mathbb R \cong \operatorname T_t\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C \cong \operatorname T_{h_2(t)}\mathbb C$, with respect to which ${\operatorname d}h_{2, t}$ is multiplication by $i h_2(t)$.  On the other hand, we have to choose identifications of the tangent spaces to $\operatorname S^1$ with $\mathbb R$—one very natural choice is to identify, for each $z \in \operatorname S^1$, $\Delta t \in \mathbb R$ with the tangent vector at $t = 0$ to the curve $t \mapsto z e^{i\Delta t\cdot t}$—and then ${\operatorname d}h_{1, t}$ is the identity map for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli, thanks for the proposed edit. I was in the middle of a more expansive edit when you proposed it, which wound up overwriting it, but I think I covered the same territory.

Answer (score 1):

The usefulness of differentials  comes from the fact that a linear function is very simple to calculate and that, by definition, the differential of a function $f$ defined on a vector space $V$ at a point $x\in V$, among all possible approximations of $f(x+h)$ by a linear function, is the best possible approximation, in the sense that
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+\mathrm df_x(h)+o\bigl(\|h\|\bigr).$$

Comment: Just to be "that guy", a linear function need not be very simple to calculate:  there is a linear function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & \text{the Riemann hypothesis is true} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, and it is very difficult to calculate away from $x = 0$.  But of course what you meant is clear.

Comment: Just to nitpick a bit, you do not really define a linear function, but choose which linear function a function $f$ will be equal to.

Answer (score 0):

(Initially a comment.)

At a technical level a differential is linear by definition. At a secondary level because linear maps are simple. For example

1. They scale area by a constant factor, called the Jacobian (even in case of $R^n \to R^m$ is $n\leq m$.
2. Ultimately (1) is responsible for the change of variables formula, the area formula (think formula for surface area in calculus), and co-area formula.
3. Linearity of the derivative also gives the notion of tangent space to manifolds. Assuming our manifold is embedded in $R^N$, the tangent space is the image of the derivative of a local parameterization.